# Auto recovery for a failed CF app on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

is there a way to force a cf app to restart if it crashes and is not responsive?

I could not find a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Actually if your application crashes and the instance **stops**, Bluemix already tries to automatically restart it.

However when a service that you bind to an app crashes, problems such as outages, exceptions, and connection failures might occur on the app. Bluemix does not automatically restart the app to recover from these problems. This behavior is by design of Cloud Foundry. You can manually restart the app by typing the following command in the command line interface:

```
cf restart <appname>
```

If you need to automate this you could take a look at the [Bluemix Auto-Scaling Service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/auto-scaling/). There you can configure even complex Auto-Scaling policies like, for example: "if the CPU usage exceeds 90% for more than one minute, provision a new instance of the application" or "when one instance is having an unacceptable response time provision a new one". You can also unprovision an instance when it is not used or when it is not used enough according to your policy.

Take a look also at [Handle the Unexpected with Bluemix Auto-Scaling](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/03/handle-unexpected-bluemix-auto-scaling/).